# Retrieving images from Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am storing images in an S3 bucket, but I'm not able to display the link to the image. This is the error I get:

```
<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>8CAF92C03A75648C</RequestId>
  <HostId>
     ocfqcRiXsJoV0mBom0z+nmV3seEMRpdBMvDddy1sgQrIOq19/UvK6BmurlM8v20zGIvh2ITHjYc=
  </HostId>
</Error>
```

I need to have images display on various domains, but more than I would be able to handle in making CORS rules for each one.

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

How can I open this bucket up so that images are publicly able to be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to do with CORS, it's the S3 bucket configuration.

If you are comfortable with the entire bucket being public-read, [here's the official AWS guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html), and my rough steps:

1. enable web hosting, add index/error document defaults.
2. add the public-read policy (below; only need to change BUCKETNAME)
3. profit!

policy:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As a caveat, if you are using S3 to host static content, you should really be using a CDN (like CloudFront) and paying attention to your cache-control header.